# Python: obtain programmatically the code of a function

Tags: python

I'm playing with [tf.autograph.to_code](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/to_code) and I'm wondering if
there is a way to obtain programmatically the **code** of a standard Python function.

Something like this:

```py
def sign(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 'Positive'
    else:
        return 'Negative or zero'
mycode = magic_function(sign)
print(mycode)
```

Returning:

> ```
> if x > 0:
>     return 'Positive'
> else:
>     return 'Negative or zero'
> ```

Comment: It does! Apparently this is a duplicate question.
Thanks!

Comment: If it does, then delete yours as it *is* a duplicate.